# Facebook Graph API return error when call Business Discovery API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

When I call the api:

```
 graph.facebook.com/userid?fields=business_discovery.username(name){followers_count,media_count}
```

in Graph API explore, I got an invalid parameter error:

> (#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (business_discovery) on node type (User)

Could anyone please explain to me what I miss in the API url?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Do you need the instagram_basic, instagram_manage_insights , manage_pages or pages_show_list permissions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This only works for Instagram Business Accounts, but you seem to be using it with a normal user id.

As https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/user/business_discovery says,

> Instagram Platform API account IDs will not work with the new Instagram Graph API. Please use the Page node to determine the correct Instagram Business Account ID associated with the Facebook page.

You can not use this for other types of Instagram accounts, only for business accounts.

Comment: Yeah, I understand now, but I try to use another account ID but that error still occurred. 

Check this Account:
[link](https://www.instagram.com/web/search/topsearch/?context=user&count=0&query=littlebittecocktails)

Comment: Is this your account to begin with? The user node you perform this request _on_ needs to be your own Instagram business account.

Comment: No it's a difference account, but it also an instagram business account

Comment: Could you please let me know how to get the Instagram business ID?
I used this:
`GET graph.facebook.com/134895793791914?fields=instagram_business_account`

Comment: I don’t think you can get this, if you don’t have admin access to the page. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/page#read

Comment: I have an accesstoken with these permissions:
[link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JAFDO1jGmQrixPZTWmwt29Sbmpphygex).

Comment: And is 134895793791914 your own account?

Comment: No, it's a Page ID, not mine

Comment: I meant, is this a page you have admin access to, or just any arbitrary page you have no connection to?

Comment: Do you need the instagram_basic, instagram_manage_insights , manage_pages or pages_show_list permissions

Comment: the link you reference in the answer is not valid anymore

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that the instagram account was not connected to the page when the access-token was issue i.e. I added the instagram account after connecting the app.

So what worked for me was to remove the app, make sure that the instagram account is connected to the page the connect the app. Now the access token works.

Comment: So basically there is no way, through the API to pull data for another account that isn't yours?

Comment: No way to do that. If you are in the business of collecting data of people without their knowledge then you are in the wrong business. I am sure you are aware of Cambridge Analytica for example, and the history of Facebook and privacy: https://techcrunch.com/2018/04/10/a-brief-history-of-facebooks-privacy-hostility-ahead-of-zuckerbergs-testimony/. Also Facebook actively opposes people and companies trying to skim data off their platforms, because information is their source of income and they don't want to share, and because of all the privacy related law suits they could get involved with.

Comment: No, not exactly. I work for a talent agency and we want to display the number of followers our talent has on their profiles on our website.

Comment: Ah I see. If your "talent" gives all necessary permissions to an Instagram app you create (https://developers.facebook.com/) that also gets the approval of Facebook, then you can get that information but only from "talent that has gave the permission to that app to get that info. What is crucial here is that "talents" has to give permission to access that info. Then the app need to collect the data, calculate aggregated stats  and provider the result for display on the website.

Comment: Yes makes sense. I think long-term that it would be unsustainable in terms of having to maintain many permissions. We will just omit this.  Thanks!